# receiving other reference type in Java

Tags: parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

There is a parameter which is reference type, and can it receive other reference type? 
 for instance, there is a code below

```
fr = new FileReader("d:\\test.txt");
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

the BufferedReader class receives FileReader type but I see in the JAVA API

```
BufferedReader(Reader in)
```

receives Reader type.

I know Reader class is abstract but it doesn't give me a clue.
How is getting other types of reference as a parameter possible?

Comment: You need to understand inheritance concept of oops https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: And [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) is also relevant

Comment: @alfasin do you mean if FileReader type fr is passed to Buffer reader's parameter it will be upcasted to Object class type?

Comment: @R.S. So it is concept of up casting

Comment: yes it is upcasting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileReader` is a subclass of `InputStreamReader`, which is a subclass of `Reader`. That said, all public methods and variables from `Reader` are available in `FileReader`.

Comment: are you saying it is up casting?